# Using variables in a class in django

Tags: python, django, class

I am trying to make a chart that displays the temperature and timestamp data, however I want to filter it. The current database this data is being taken from looks like this:
[image]

And I only want the graph to display data from the specific user that is already logged in. Furthermore, I have pages for each room ID showing the data from that room and with that user, and this is where I want the graph to be displayed. So you login and go to a specific room page and the graph shows the temperature and timestamp data from that room (and of course with that username). The current structure displays the chart by uploading the JSON formatted data to a link called API, and the code to get this API data up is displayed here.

```
class ChartData(APIView, models.Model):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        labels = []
        for e in Post.objects.all():
            labels.append(e.timestamp)
         #   print(e.room_id)
          #  print(e.username)
            #print(e.temperature)
        chartLabel = "my data"
        chartdata = []
        for e in Post.objects.all():
            chartdata.append(e.temperature)
        data ={
                     "labels":labels,
                     "chartLabel":chartLabel,
                     "chartdata":chartdata,
             }
        return Response(data)
```

So right now it takes every temperature and timestamp in the database and puts that on the chart. In order to change it so it only takes the data where the username is the same one as the logged in username and the room ID is correct I assume I need to put something into the authentication or permission classes. Or if I could pass in the request.user.get_username() argument into this class (which works on my other views) I could filter the object set via this. furthermore in a previous view I have this:

```
def roomview(request, room_id):
    logged_in_username = request.user.get_username()
    Posts = Post.objects.filter(username=logged_in_username).filter(room_id=room_id)
    context = {
        'Posts' : Posts
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/roomview.html', context)
```

This code is what shows the objects from the same username and the same room id that is being selected and displays them on that page. I need to find a way to pass this room_id into the chartData class so it only uploads a JSON file of the data being required based on the room id and the user that is logged in, but I am struggling, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update, I got the charts working specifically to each room so now I just need to make it filter by user

Comment: usually pages send information as part of url: `?room_id=....` and function can get it from `request`

Answer (score 0):

So to get the username I had to implement the following authentication, in settings.py I added this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
      'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
      'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
   ]
}
```

Then in views.py I added this:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        UserIn = (request.user.username)
```

For the Room ID all I had to do was this:

```
class ChartData(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            inroom = (value)
```